# Displaying a greeting to one user selected from a database

Tags: php, sql

I execute the following SQL statement to get back an data object into a variable.

```
  try {
    $getUser = $db->query('select * from user where user.user_id = '.$user_id);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
```

from this I print out the information on the page where necessary e.g. the following:

```
  <?php
  foreach ($getUser as $user) {
    echo '
    <div class="col-wd-12">
      <div class="col bodyHead">Welcome, '.$user['email'].'</div>
    </div>
    ';
  }
  ?>
```

The question is I know the size of the $getUser array to always be one. 
Am I doing this the correct way when returning the information? Is there a better way where I do not need to use a foreach loop everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is I know the size of the $getUser array to always be one.

No you don't. You *assume* it is - and it's *probably* a safe assumption to make. But actually **knowing** that `user_id` is a primary key is the job of the underlying database, not of your application.

You *would* know that 1 record is returned, if the query you send to the database says "give me one record where user_Id is equal to..." - if your backend is [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) that's done with a `LIMIT` clause.

Your query is missing a terminating semicolon... but the worst offense is the concatenation of the `.$user_id` into the WHERE clause. Where's that value coming from? Is there *any slightest chance* that it might not be containing the value you're expecting, and that concatenating it could result in unexpected SQL statements being injected into your query? If that's the case, then your query might actually be returning *all rows*, not just one.

See [*give me parameterized SQL, or give me death!*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) (or many, many, many other online resources) for more details.

Comment: aha I should have been more specific about the $user_id. I have a check prior to this that ensures its set to a single id only. BUT needless to say, thank you! Most helpful

Answer (score 1):

As @Mat's Mug already suggested, your code is open to SQL injection, which makes it possible to read out any database values (and also may make it possible to execute commands, write and read files, etc).

Casting the value to int *somewhere* may prevent SQL injection in this situation, but you *will* eventually make a mistake and be vulnerable. It is impossible to always be sure that each value is already cast/filtered in some way when this happens somewhere else. You really need to use prepared statements.

You are also vulnerable to XSS via email.

Also:

- `getUser` should be named `users`. It's not a query, it's the result of a query, ie users.
- SQL keywords should be all upper-case, making them easier to distinguish from variables and making your query easier to read.
- use at least 4 spaces of indentation to make your code more readable.